# How to trigger UICollectionView's reload method from another function

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, reload

I have a UICollection view which loads just fine when I launch the app. My problem is, I need to reload it with fresh data when a button from the menubar is clicked.  Here's my code.  To keep things simple, I've greatly trimmed it down

```
    class RootViewController:  UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource{//The view controller that contains the collection view
        var carouselCollectionView: UICollectionView!//A reference to the collectionview
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 1, bottom: 1, right: 1)
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: carouselWindowWidth, height: carouselWindowHeight)
            layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5

            carouselCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
            carouselCollectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)
            carouselCollectionView.delegate = self
            carouselCollectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            carouselCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

            self.view.addSubview(carouselCollectionView) //Add the collectionview to the main view(self)
        }//End viewDidLoad


        //Delegates for collectionViewController go here
        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return currentImageArray.count
        }


        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            /*...*/
         }

         func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
             /*...*/
         }


         //This function is triggered when a menuItem on the menuBar is clicked.  It it supposed to fetch some data from some source, then reload the collectionview
        func reloadData(VC:UIViewController){
            /*...*/
            carouselCollectionView.reloadData()
        }

    }//End RootViewController
```

I get this error when `reloadData()` is run

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Any ideas on how to do this correctly? Any help greatly appreciated

PS. The data as expected when I run `reloadData()` within `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Try to keep breakpoint and check that which data source method is generating this error.

Comment: I think you should check currentImageArray and return 0 if currentImageArray is nil

Answer (score -1):

Ok You need to handle this with 2 steps:

1. Create an @IBOutlet of collection view and connect it with your collection view in storyboard : yourCollectionView
2. Declare and initialize: var currentImageArray = UIImage
3. On your @IBAction of the button:

// do your stuff
// and then

yourCollectionView.reloadData()

Let me know when it works !!!

Comment: The Incliner :Can't do that because my entire application is written programatically(without storyboards)

Comment: hmmm. The error that you get happens when you force unwrap a variable with ! thinking its not going to be nil...but it tuns out to be. Try checking the lines where you assign values to cell...if you are trying to force unwrap any value....Also check if 'currentImageArray' is not nil....Let me know what happens